# memory.dll instaled but error type using memory;

Tags: c#, vb.net

memory.dll is installed but error type using memory;
I don't use any command, why please help

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eP0AX.png)

Please let me know this solution which I am using

I am installing Nuget package memory.dll
and use in code

using memory;

Show error when namespace memory is missing, why help me?

Comment: i think it is supposed to be `using System.Memory`. Also try to create a more concise question, this one is rather vague (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Please read [why we ask that you not post text as images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/11810933).  Please 

Edit your post

to include the text in-addition-to or in-place-of the image.  Thanks!